# Must fermions be particle sized? Does pauli exclusion principle apply to large bodies?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, fermions, pauli-exclusion-principle

I am wondering if all fermions must be quantum in nature or if I can build a 'classically sized' fermion.

For example, if I ensure that the total spin of all protons, neutrons and electrons in a bulk solid is 1/2, it should be a fermion. But it would seem strange and useless to me to apply pauli exclusion principle to such a body. I suppose that the degeneracy pressure in neutron stars would be an example of Pauli exclusion at large scales.

Could I for example, generate an analog to a Fermi gas using a collection of billiard balls that all have spin 1/2? Could they then occupy the same space if the respective spins are antiparallel?

It seems according to this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/61102a/which_of_the_four_fundamental_forces_is/) and the [wiki on the exchange interaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchange_interaction) that there is no analog to the pauli exclusion principle on classical scales. But I am not certain if that means that principle does not scale to classical scales or if it means there is no law similar to it on classical scales.

Comment: Useful search terms are “quantum fluid” and “fermion condensate.” Many-body effects can be nontrivial; consider the bosonic “Cooper pairs” of electrons which transport charge in a superconductor.